# Why do I get java.lang.NullPointerException when I connect via RDP or change the resolution?

Tags: java, windows, console, console-application

I'm running a console application under Windows on a remote remote computer.

The following error seems to appears regularly when I log into the remote computer via RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol). It also seems to occur on my local machine when I resize the desktop, or if the nVidia video driver crashes (which is rarely).

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at twslaunch.jtscomponents.effect.i.c(i.java:172)
at jtscomponents.plaf.ze.run(ze.java:178)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The problem occurs under Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and both Java v6 and Java v7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer completely resolved the issue - now, when I log in via RDP, the `java.lang.NullPointerException` messages have completely disappeared.

See [Why do I receive Java exceptions when I log in to my computer via Remote Desktop while MATLAB is running?](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-A2R1E3/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-A2R1E3)

Quote:

> One resolution is based on the fact that for slower connections, the
>   theme is changed while logging in. To resolve this, you require a Fast
>   connection to your remote machine (10 Mbps or higher with low
>   latency). Multiple monitor setups and drastic resolution changes
>   between the two computers complicate this issue. These cases are not
>   covered here.
>
> Assuming the requirements are met, you can change the Connection speed
>   setting under the "Experience" tab on the Remote Desktop client to
>   "LAN (10 Mbps or higher)" before connecting.

[image]

> NOTE: If the above causes an undesired experience using Remote
>   Desktop, you may revert back to the old connection speed setting in
>   Remote Desktop and make sure that the look and feel of both operating
>   systems is set to the same. This can be changed by navigating from the
>   Control Panel to Display and then Themes.